# Generating XML from stored data in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a dtd file and many different xml files generated according to the this dtd. I want to store content of this files in database and generate them on the fly using java SE6. I already generated java bean files using jaxb with dtd option. My question is about storing xml values in db preserving element hierarchies. For instance following fragment is valid in my xml:

```
<map name="axisOptions">
    <property name="wsdlServiceElement" value="GenericService"/>
</map>
<property name="style" value="rpc"/>
```

In order to differentiate these property elements, I am planning to store parentid in every row in db and understand where to put which property.
For the example above, I drawed following table. first property record will have parent as **map** and the second property will have parent as **null**
I am not sure if this will be the best practice, any other idea how to do this efficiently?

```
type    key     value       parent
map     name    axisOptions null
property name   wsdlS..El.. map
property value  Gen..S..ce  map
property name   style       null
property value  rpc         null
```

Comment: If you already are using JAXB to represent the XML then you can always go backwards and marshal the JAXB objects back into XML.  Knowing this you have a number of options to persist this to a database, you can annotate these objects for JPA and store them in that way.

Comment: Actually I am trying to set jaxb bean fields with values stored in database.Currently I am assuming there will be no storing.

Comment: This is quite a broad topic about how to effectively load an object with values from a database.  You can still use JPA for this but unless you try something and post your attempt then we can't help you.